# Using ajax to change iframe

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, iframe

Is it possible to change the URL of an iframe without leaving the page. I.e. Ajax
If so how can this be done.
Thanks so much

Comment: Yes you can asynchronously change the url of an iframe. AJAX has nothing to do with it unless you're retrieving the URL from the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, using just javascript (I used jQuery)..

Example is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/pYG2z/

```
HTML:
<iframe id="googframe" src="http://www.google.com"></iframe>
<input type=button id="changeframe" value="Change">


JS:
$('#changeframe').click(function() {
  $('#googframe').attr('src','http://www.msn.com'); 
});
```

Comment: @Fosco how can we use a text link instead of a button?

Comment: Actually, that example uses jQuery. Setting the `src` attribute will cause the IFrame to be loaded.

Answer (score 2):

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('your_iframe');
iframe.src = 'http://example.com/';
```